# Effect of dark matter on measuring our weight

Tags: astronomy, dark-matter

We know that 95% of the matter in the universe, and all around us, and in our room is dark matter.
Dark matter does interact with normal matter only through gravitation.

So, does it have an effect on our measurement of our weight?
Specifically, shouldn't it have a huge effect on our measurement of our weight?

Comment: If you mean the first sentence to imply that *"We know that 95% of the matter [...] in our room is dark matter"*, then this is not correct. That is only true on large scales---like that of the galaxy. Cue the usual Douglas Adams quote about the size of space and the distance down the road to the chemist's.

Answer (score 2):

> We know that 95% of the matter in the universe, and all around us, and in our room is dark matter.

You are conflating dark matter and dark energy here. About 5% of the mass-energy of the universe is ordinary matter. Most (over 2/3) of that mass-energy is in the form of dark energy. The remaining 32% of this mass-energy is mass, or matter. About 84%, maybe a bit more, of that matter is dark matter.

> So, does it have an effect on our measurement of our weight? Specifically, shouldn't it have a huge effect on our measurement of our weight?

The effect is theoretically present but it is unmeasurably small.

Ordinary matter clumps together to form planets, stars, star clusters. Dark matter doesn't do that.  Dark matter doesn't interact electromagnetically, neither with ordinary matter or with dark matter. It does clumps together, but only to the extent allowed by gravitation. This means galaxies have clouds (or halos) of dark matter associated with them. These dark matter halos are widely dispersed. The quantity of dark matter within the solar system is much, much smaller than is the quantity of ordinary matter within the solar system. It's smaller yet within the confines of a condensed object (e.g., the Sun or the Earth). Almost all of the Earth's mass comes from ordinary matter.